# Code which display the information of block as per user selection

Tags: c#, autocad

This is my code to select blocks in the dwg as per user selection and print the details of block on dwg file with the help of mtext but mtext is not working it doesnt print any thing. It gives me the exception.

```
    [CommandMethod("LAT")]
    public void ListAttributes()
    {
        Document acDoc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Editor ed =
          Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
        Database db =
          HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;
        Transaction tr =
          db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();

        // Start the transaction
        try
        {
            // Build a filter list so that only
            // block references are selected
            TypedValue[] filList = new TypedValue[1] {
      new TypedValue((int)DxfCode.Start, "INSERT")
    };
            SelectionFilter filter =
              new SelectionFilter(filList);
            PromptSelectionOptions opts =
              new PromptSelectionOptions();
            opts.MessageForAdding = "Select block references: ";
            PromptSelectionResult res =
              ed.GetSelection(opts, filter);

            // Do nothing if selection is unsuccessful
            if (res.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
                return;

            SelectionSet selSet = res.Value;
            ObjectId[] idArray = selSet.GetObjectIds();
            foreach (ObjectId blkId in idArray)
            {
                BlockReference blkRef =
                  (BlockReference)tr.GetObject(blkId,
                    OpenMode.ForRead);
                BlockTableRecord btr =
                  (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(
                    blkRef.BlockTableRecord,
                    OpenMode.ForWrite
                  );
                ed.WriteMessage(
                  "\nBlock: " + btr.Name
                );
                //btr.Dispose();

                AttributeCollection attCol =
                  blkRef.AttributeCollection;
                foreach (ObjectId attId in attCol)
                {
                    MText mtext = new MText();
                    mtext.SetDatabaseDefaults();
                    mtext.Height = 2;

                    AttributeReference attRef =
                      (AttributeReference)tr.GetObject(attId,
                        OpenMode.ForRead);

                    string str =
                        ////("\n  Attribute Tag: "
                        ////  + attRef.Tag
                        ////  + "\n    Attribute String: "
                        ("\n" + attRef.TextString);
                    mtext.Contents = ("hELLO");
                    acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage("\n" + str);
                    btr.AppendEntity(mtext);
                    tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(mtext, true);
                }
            }
            tr.Commit();
        }
        catch (Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception ex)
        {
            ed.WriteMessage(("Exception: " + ex.Message));
        }
        finally
        {
            tr.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: where is the code? you should add more detail.
no detail in original post even though up voted?

Comment: The code was in previous edition. I suggest 'ObjectARX' tag.

Answer (score 3):

You have to iterate through the Model Space and find all Hatches.
Here is one of way to perform it:

```
[CommandMethod("FindAllHatches")]
public static void FindAllHatches()
{
    Document acDoc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;

    acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage("\nSearching for Hatches");

    var db = acDoc.Database;
    using (Transaction transaction = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
    {
        ObjectId idModelSpace = SymbolUtilityServices.GetBlockModelSpaceId(db);

        BlockTableRecord modelSpace =
            transaction.GetObject(idModelSpace, OpenMode.ForRead) as
            BlockTableRecord;

        var sbReportText = new StringBuilder(); //usging System.Text
        double fTotalArea = 0.0;
        int nTotalHatches = 0;

        foreach (var objId in modelSpace)
        {
            var entity = transaction.GetObject(objId, OpenMode.ForRead);
            Hatch hatch = entity as Hatch;
            if (hatch == null)
                continue; //not hatch

            nTotalHatches++;
            fTotalArea += hatch.Area;

            acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage("\nFound Hatch Area={0}", hatch.Area);
            sbReportText.AppendFormat("Hatch Area={0}\n", hatch.Area);
        }

        if (nTotalHatches == 0)
            return; //no hatches found

        modelSpace.UpgradeOpen();

        MText acMText = new MText();
        acMText.SetDatabaseDefaults();

        sbReportText.AppendFormat("Count = {0}, Total Area = {1}",
            nTotalHatches, fTotalArea);
        acMText.Contents = sbReportText.ToString();

        modelSpace.AppendEntity(acMText);
        transaction.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(acMText, true);

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Your `acBlkTblRec` is `modelSpace` from my example.

Comment: thanx Dmitriy just one thing i need that i want to display this output on my drawing sheets i.e. on dwg file how can i do that?

Comment: when im use mtext its gives me internal error and suddenly my autocad is colse plz help.

Comment: In order to attach new entity ensure that `BlockTableRecord` is opened for `Write`

Comment: You have to do this stuff in two stages: 1)Calculate whatever you need 2)Add mtext with your calculation result. I'd split it into two separate methods for `1` and `2`. So main part of method `1` is in my answer and method `2` is in your code.

Comment: But that mtext override and i want answer in seprate lines i mean display area of hatch seprately in different lines.

Comment: You can return `IEnumerable<string>` and instead of `WriteMessage` write `yield return string.Format("\nFound Hatch Area={0}", hatch.Area)`. Thus you'll be able to make common string using [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Or you can accumulate answer with `StringBuilder`

Comment: I a not get that can u plz rewrite code using string.join?

Comment: plz help me out there

Comment: Sorry for the delay @Ajay. I've updated my answer. Now it generates the text in 0,0,0.

Comment: Hello,recently i develope new command to identify blocks in dwg file,and i want to display that all blocks information on dwg file but mtext is not displayed.plz suggest

Comment: i am develope command in visual studio 2016 and used in autocad 2011so can i used it in autocad 2016?

Comment: Hi Ajay! Please make a full seperate question.

Comment: Actually my questions are full thats why i am asking question here.

Comment: I will edit my question and add my new code for which i was asking current question

Comment: Blocks information and Hatch area information don't look similar.

Comment: This time i am confuse about mtext

Comment: I am using vs2015 and autocad 2011 when i develope any program in vs and run in autocad its running successfully but when same code i will run in autocad 2016 its give me exception.Why?

Comment: This is defenetly the seperate question!

Comment: Yes Do you have any solution ?

Comment: My friend! Please don't mix questions. Remember that your question and my answer must help to someone in the future. There was the question about Hatch. Now you've changed it and my answer seems useless.

Comment: Sorry for that i will change it to previous.

Comment: You have a solution for the above question its urgent for me.

Comment: There is not enough details. Write separate question with code example and exception details.